# Execute onsubmit function in HTML form only with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

As below snippet shows, by clicking on plus icon both `submitFunc()` and `meanFunc()` would be executed. But I want to execute `submitFunc()` only when Submit button pressed.

```js
function submitFunc(e) {
  alert('submit')
}
function meanFunc(e) {
  alert('click')
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- font-awesome -->
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form class="save-form" action="" method="post" target="votar" onsubmit="submitFunc(event)">      
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row m-2" >
      <input class="form-control" id="meaning" placeholder="Meaning" style="width:75%">
      <button class="btn rounded text-left"><i class='plus-btn fas fa-plus-circle' onclick="meanFunc(event)"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button's default type is submit. Just set it to button instead, e.g. `<button class="btn rounded text-left" type="button">`:

```js
function submitFunc(e) {
  alert('submit')
}
function meanFunc(e) {
  alert('click')
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- font-awesome -->
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form class="save-form" action="" method="post" target="votar" onsubmit="submitFunc(event)">      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row m-2" >
      <input class="form-control" id="meaning" placeholder="Meaning" style="width:75%">
      <button class="btn rounded text-left" type="button"><i class='plus-btn fas fa-plus-circle' onclick="meanFunc(event)"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a return false to the function and to the call on the plus icon, below is the modified snippet

```js
function submitFunc(e) {
  alert('submit')
}
function meanFunc(e) {
  alert('click')
return false;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <!-- font-awesome -->
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form class="save-form" action="" method="post" target="votar" onsubmit="submitFunc(event)">      <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row m-2" >
      <input class="form-control" id="meaning" placeholder="Meaning" style="width:75%">
      <button class="btn rounded text-left"><i class='plus-btn fas fa-plus-circle' onclick="return meanFunc(event);"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">
</form>
```